# mock outputs in Terragrunt dependency

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terragrunt

I want to use Terragrunt to deploy this example:  https://github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-eks-blueprints/blob/main/examples/complete-kubernetes-addons/main.tf

So far, I was able to create the VPC/EKS resource without a problem, I separated each module into a different module directory, and everything worked as expected.

When I tried to do the same for the `Kubernetes-addons` module, I faced an issue with the data source trying to call to the cluster and failing since the cluster wasn't created at this point.

Here's my `terragrunt.hcl` which I'm trying to execute for this specific module:

```
...
terraform { 
  source = "git::git@github.com:aws-ia/terraform-aws-eks-blueprints.git//modules/kubernetes-addons?ref=v4.6.1"
}

locals {
  # Extract needed variables for reuse
  cluster_version = "${include.envcommon.locals.cluster_version}"
  name =  "${include.envcommon.locals.name}"

}
dependency "eks" {
  config_path = "../eks"

  mock_outputs = {
    eks_cluster_endpoint = "https://000000000000.gr7.eu-west-3.eks.amazonaws.com"
    eks_oidc_provider = "something"
    eks_cluster_id = "something"
  }
}
inputs = {
  eks_cluster_id = dependency.eks.outputs.cluster_id
  eks_cluster_endpoint = dependency.eks.outputs.eks_cluster_endpoint
  eks_oidc_provider = dependency.eks.outputs.eks_oidc_provider
  eks_cluster_version = local.cluster_version
...
}
```

The error that I'm getting here:
`

```
INFO[0035]
  Error: error reading EKS Cluster (something): couldn't find resource
   with data.aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster,
    on data.tf line 7, in data "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster":
      7: data "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster" {
```

`

Comment: Hi there, in your `inputs` block I see a typo, you are missing the `eks_` prefix in the `cluster_id` variable reference. I don't think this is causing your problem though.

Answer (score 0):

The `kubernetes-addons` module is deploying addons into an existing Kubernetes cluster. If you don't have a cluster running (apparently you don't have one when you're mocking the `cluster_id` variable), then you get the error of not having the `aws_eks_cluster` data source.

You need to create the K8s cluster first, before you can start deploying the addons.

Comment: Hi, I understand your point. However, when I'm trying to create the cluster using the example from above, without Terragrunt, everything is working.
Terraform Plan and Terraform Apply work include the `add-ons` part, so it's unclear what the difference is here.

Comment: Can you show your TG module for creating the cluster? Because the code you pasted creates the add-ons, not the cluster.